# How to draw ecg graph realtime in android?

Tags: android, graph

I had used multiple libraries like mpandroidchart,scichart,achartengine,graphview but i cant get output like below image.

What should i try?or shall i used canvas approach?

I want to draw a ecg graph on basis of graph plotting points(short value) coming from hardware continuously.so if hardware is off at that time you get single line with no data.

[image: Multiple data points connected and get this type of output to form ecg graph]

Comment: Hi Sagar, do you get any solution to this?

Comment: Hai, Any one found the answer?